# Excel VBA macro create new value from 2 entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sort values from an entire column.
I do have one column city which have different values of 0 or 1 ( 0% and 100% )
There are 90 000 rows.
I'll need to do a percentage by compiling the values of 0 and 1 by doing the average
I want that value to appear in the column I

[image]

Like what I want is that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVERAGEIF combined with IF

> [Function
> AVERAGEIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642)

My fake data:

[image]

My formula at C2 (and drag down)

```
=IF(A2=A1;"";AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$13;A2;$B$2:$B$13))
```

Anyways, I would suggest to use indeed Pivot Tables:

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

With Pivot Tables, you could group your data using cities field, and then calculate the average easily, and just 1 single row per city instead of those empty rows

[image]